# SQLite import fields with new lines

Tags: bash, sqlite, sed, tr

I have some data that is delimited by the `\002` character. This is what I use to import it:

```
cat data.txt             \
  | tr -d '\r'           \
  | tr    '\n'   '\003'  \
  | tr    '\t'   ' '     \
  | tr    '\001' '\t'    \
  | tr    '\002' '\n'    \
  | sed 's%\003%\\n%g'   \
  > data-formatted.txt
```

This command erases `\r` characters, changes `\n` to `\\n`, and changes `\002` to new lines `\n`

Formatting before:

http://wikisend.com/download/486524/data.txt

```
Not Escaped:
1 new
line 2 new
line
2   

Escaped:
1\001new\nline\002\001
2\001new\nline\n2\002\001
```

Formatting after:

```
Not Escaped:
1   new\\nline  
2   new\\nline\\n2  

Escaped:
1\tnew\\nline\t\n
2\tnew\\nline\\n2\t\n
```

The problem is that my data is importing the `\n` instead of a new line.

Here is my import script:

```
import.txt:

    .separator  "\t"
    .import     data-formatted.txt my_table
```

And my import command:
`cat import.txt | sqlite3 my.db`

To test the data:

```
echo 'SELECT * FROM my_table;' | sqlite3 my.db

    1|new\nline|
    2|new\nline\n2|
```

How do I import \n as a newline in the data field?

Comment: Can you show a part of `data-formatted.txt`?

Comment: I wonder, could it be possible to wrap-up those newlines around quotes? `1   "new<newline>line"` or `1   'new<newline>line'`. Have you tried? I'm actually just following the concept of csv's.

Comment: It might work. But wouldn't that require a complex `sed` command?

Comment: Well I think some would find a way for it who knows. But at least you can have a solution for that. The only problem would be the conversion. But for now you should first try to know if it would work. You can try editing and importing it manually for now. I also recommend explaining how you convert your data. Perhaps a raw example would help too. There could be a better way.

Comment: OK I added an example, too. I hope it makes sense.

Comment: `sed "s%\t%\t\"/%1` | `sed "s%\t%\"\t/%2` should be that "complicated sed" id you want it

If you give us a proper example of raw data (maybe one we could download) then I'm sure we can make short work of this.

Comment: OK I uploaded the file: http://wikisend.com/download/486524/data.txt

Comment: @redolent I studied your data and finally got some output. The code I posted could only convert your data to csv but we could start there. Please check if you can use it to import your data. We'll try to make updates if it's not enough.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this Ruby code. This would convert your data to csv format.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'csv'

data = File.read(ARGV.shift)

set = data.split("\x02\x0a").map{|e| e.strip.split("\x01")}.select{|e| e.any?}

output = CSV.generate do |csv|
    set.each do |e|
        csv << e
    end
end

puts output
```

Save it to a file like `script.rb` and run `ruby script.rb data > output.csv`

I hope your data is not that large though. If it lags try using a faster generator like [FasterCSV](http://fastercsv.rubyforge.org/).

Example output:

```
1,"new
line"
2,"new
line
2"
```